# How can I get the value of an HTML attribute in Blazor?

Tags: blazor

I'm just starting out with Blazor and I wan't to get the value of an HTML attribute an pass it into a method as a parameter (I'm calling the method in the @onchange event). How can I do this? Or is it even possible?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="foo" @onchange="(MyMethod())"></input>
```

### Edit

I got this code:
`@foreach ((int key, string value) in myDictionary) { <input type="checkbox" id="@key" @onchange="MyMethod()" /> }` I wan't to add all ids of the checked checkboxes into a list. This happens in the "MyMethod" but to do that I somehow have to pass the id of the checkbox as a parameter into this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass `MyMethod()` (with parentesis)  your are calling the function, you need to pass without that so you pass the reference.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="foo" @onchange="MyMethod"></input>
```

## Edit

You should pass an array function that call your method, this way you don't call it on every render, but only when the `onchange` event is trigger.

```
@foreach ((int key, string value) in myDictionary)
{
    <input type="checkbox" id="@key" @onchange="(() => MyMethod(key))" />
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your tip though this doesn't answer my question can you help me with that?

Comment: @Computergy could you explain better what you need? `I wan't to get the value of an HTML attribute an pass it into a method as a parameter` What attribute? What method?

Comment: I got this code:  `@foreach ((int key, string value) in myDictionary)
            {
                <input type="checkbox"  id="@key" @onchange="MyMethod()" />
            }` I wan't to add all ids of the checked checkboxes into a list. This happens in the "MyMethod" but to do that I somehow have to pass the id of the checkbox as a parameter into this method.

Comment: @Computergy now it's a bit more clear, please check my edit